# Docker Container DISALLOW/DISABLE communication between containers

Tags: docker

actually i'm trying to figure out the docker container linking feature.

I read this tutorial from docker docs: https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/
And im actually able to link two containers zu allow tcp communication between two containers :)
BUT im not able to create&run two containers and DISALLOW/DISABLE the tcp communication.

--> So where is my Bug?

My Systemconfig:

Host:       CentOS 7
Docker version: 1.4.1
Docker API :    1.16

Options: --icc=false, --iptables=true

This are my Commands:

1. docker run -it -d -name container1 dm:5000/silver/tocmat /bin/bash
2. docker run -it -d -name container2 dm:5000/silver/tocmat /bin/bash
3. docker exec container1 /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
4. docker ecec container2 /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start

IP of container1: 172.17.0.2
IP of container2: 172.17.0.3

And now the tcp test:

docker exec container1 curl -v 172.17.0.3

- About to connect() to 172.17.0.3 port 8400 (#0)
- Trying 172.17.0.6...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0* Connected to 172.17.0.3 (172.17.0.3) port 8400 (#0)

So what the hell im doing wrong? I thought this shouldn't be possible without the linking feature?!
Have i completely misunderstood the Container linking/networking (on the same host)?!

Answer (score 0):

I think you were just hit by this bug: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12071.

I can verify that this does work in Docker 1.6. Upgrading should fix things for you.

Comment: That is exactly the config i decriped:


root      3081     1  0 09:40 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/docker -d -H fd:// -H tcp://0.0.0.0:8181 --icc=false --iptables=true

tcp via 172.17.0.0 is still possible... :-(

What im doing wrong?!

Comment: Oh, sorry. In that case I'd try to make a repeatable set of steps to show the problem and file an issue at github, linking to the documentation. Leave tomcat out completely, as it just confuses the situation.

Comment: I just had a bunch of issues with icc and found the above bug. I had almost the opposite problem (docker was denying connections it shouldn't have due to the problem fixed by https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/11526 )